# Find the quotient and remainder of dividing $−17$ by $3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

So I was practicing for a test by reviewing textbook questions and I ran into this problem. I understand the concept of quotient and remainder but how would you approach this if you are dealing with a negative value?

Comment: Find largest number smaller than -17 that is a multiple of 3. then substract and continue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing discrete mathematics / number theory, then we usually define the quotient and remainder as follows: The quotient and remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$ is
$$
a=bq+r
$$
where $q$ and $r$ are integers, $q$ is the quotient, and $r$ is the remainder.  Moreover, $0\leq r<b$.

In your case, $a=-17$ and $b=3$.  You need to find $q$ and $r$ that satisfy
$$
-17=3q+r
$$
where $0\leq r<3$, or that $r$ is $0$, $1$, or $2$.  Moving the $3q$ to the LHS, we get
$$
-17-3q=r.
$$
Since $r$ is nonnegative, $q$ must be negative, so we try a few values and find that $q=-6$ works nicely.  In fact,
$$
-17-3(-6)=-17+18=1.
$$
Therefore, the quotient is $-6$ and the remainder is $1$.  The reason that this works is that $18$ is the first multiple of $3$ which, when added to $-17$ gives a nonnegative number.

Comment: What did u mean when you wrote q= -6 works nicely, like what do you mean we try a few values

Comment: Also what would constitute as a "nice value" if the example was different

Comment: You need a remainder of $0$, $1$, or $2$.  So, you pick values for $q$, plug them in and see what you get for $r$.  I'm suggesting a guess and check approach - there are formulas, but they might be more confusing.